# How to go about reading slash (/) from dates using scanf - C

Tags: c

I have currently got it as :

```
scanf("%d%d%d",&day1,&mon1,&year1);
```

This works fine when I pass in a date which is to be like :

```
02-02-2016
```

However I want it to also be fine if I pass it with slash instead of the dash :

```
02/02/2016
```

I have tried this way:

```
scanf("%d/%d/%d",&day1,&mon1,&year1);
```

Now this will accept the slash(/) but however does not support dash (-)

How can it accept both ???

How would I go about doing that ? I am new to this language so some sort of advice would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: It really depends how restrictive you want to be on what people can input. Do you want them to be able to put any single character between the integers? Any number of characters? It's hard to prescribe a method when you aren't being specific on what is allowed and what is not allowed.

Comment: All I want for now to do is just allow so that dash and slash is accepted between the integers. So i can type 02-02-2016 or 02/02/2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char junk;
scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &day1, &junk,  &mon1, &junk, &year1);
```

This would work. You don't have to do anything with the characters you're reading in. If you wanted to disallow anything that isn't `-` or `/`, then you could use two variables for those chars, check them to see if they are the values you are allowing, and then `printf("Invalid input")` or react however you like.

Example, keeps reading input until correct:

```
char delim1, delim2;
do { 
    printf("Please enter date (dd-mm-yy or dd/mm/yy):");   
    scanf("%d%c%d%c%d", &day1, &delim1,  &mon1, &delim2, &year1);
} while (delim1 != '-' && delim1 != '/' && delim2 != '-' && delim2 != '/');
```

Comment: This method gives you access to both delimiter characters, so you could (for example) reject input that mixes them (_e.g._, 5/9-2017 or 3-26/2018)

Comment: If you don't check that both delimiters are the same type, you could just use `scanf("%u%*1[-/]%u%*1[-/]%u", &uday1, &umon1, &uyear1)` with the three variables being `unsigned int` type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a format string like: `"%d%*[-/]%d%*[-/]%d"` to accept only dash or slash between the numbers, but throw away whatever character is there.  (This is getting to the outer limits of my `scanf` knowledge; I don't think I've ever actually used this feature.)

Comment: This also works. In the end it depends on how restrictive you want to be.